# Is there a way to create a superposition of all the possible states?

Tags: circuit-construction, superposition

If there're four qubits in my circuit, how can I arrange my gates so that the final output state is a superposition of all the possible states of 4 qubits? (there're 16 of them in total). I've tried some 2-qubits circuits to generate the superposition states like $|\Psi^+\rangle$ and $|\Phi^-\rangle$, but I'm not exactly sure if there's a way to create the superposition of all the possible states.

Comment: Initialize them all to $\vert 0\rangle$, and Hadamard them all individually.

Comment: @Mark S Thanks!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean mapping the state $|0\rangle^{\otimes n} \to \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1} |i\rangle $ ?

If that is the case then you can just apply $H^{\otimes n}$ to the state $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$. That is, you apply a Hadamard gate to each of the qubit.

The reason for this is $H |0\rangle = \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ and so

\begin{align} \overbrace{H|0\rangle \otimes H|0\rangle \otimes \cdots \otimes H|0\rangle}^{n \ \textrm{times}} &= \overbrace{ \bigg( \dfrac{|0\rangle +|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2} } \bigg)\otimes  \bigg( \dfrac{|0\rangle +|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2} } \bigg) \otimes \cdots \otimes \bigg( \dfrac{|0\rangle +|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2} } \bigg) }^{n \ \textrm{times}} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n}}}\big( \overbrace{ |00\cdots0\rangle + |00\cdots1\rangle + \cdots + |11\cdots 1\rangle }^{2^n \ \textrm{terms} } \big)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1} |i\rangle
\end{align}

Comment: Yes!! Thank you:)

Comment: For the sake of pedantry - this is not a superposition of all possible states because there are states that are orthogonal to this. It is a superposition of all possible computational basis states.

Comment: A superposition of *all* states would be the Haar average -- which is zero.

Comment: @Markus Heinrich Thanks for the comment! Is there any link for understanding the superposition of all states?

Comment: @DaftWullie If we're being pedantic, every state is a superposition of all possible states. OP's question is nontrivial only if we interpret "superposition of A and B" as being a state in which both A and B have a nonzero contribution, but it's not possible for *all* states to have a nonzero contribution, so we must interpret this to mean that all basis states have nonzero contribution (which of course means that this is defined only with respect to a particular basis).

Comment: @Acccumulation Generally, it only makes sense the consider finite linear combinations in a basis, since the Hilbert space is finite-dimensional. This is BTW not basis-dependent. Thus, when people normally say superposition, they mean a linear combination in an orthonormal basis. However, it is also sometimes useful to express a state in a frame (overcomplete basis), just think about measurements (MUB, designs etc.).

Comment: @Zhengrong What I meant is an expression of the form $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}} \mathrm{d}\psi f(\psi) |\psi\rangle$ where $\mathrm{d}\psi$ is the (normalised) Haar measure on the unit sphere and $f$ is a measurable function. For $f=1$, the result is unitarily invariant, and thus has to be zero. It is BTW possible to write something more meaningful such as $|\varphi\rangle = d \int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}} \mathrm{d}\psi \langle \psi | \varphi \rangle|\psi\rangle$. But this is just fancy rewriting ;)

Comment: @Markus Heinrich Thank you!!

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich What do you mean by "finite linear combinations"? What are saying is not basis dependent? Whether a state has a nonzero contribution from every basis vector is basis  dependent. "Superposition" is often to mean "state with nonzero contribution from at least two basis vectors", and that is also basis dependent.

Comment: @Acccumulation You are right, the number of non-zero components is basis-dependent by definition. I don't disagree. Anyway, it does not really matter how we interpret the word superposition, in the end it's about math. I can interpret the term  "superposition of *all* states" by using an integral, like in CV quantum mechanics. Then, the expressions I gave in my comments involve *all* states (except a measure zero subset for the 2nd case). That's as close as it gets to OP's question. Whether it makes sense in some way is a different question.