# Is there a gate sending $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ to a state where some amplitudes are zero?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

By preparing $n$ qubits in $|0 \rangle ^{\otimes n}$ and then passing through the Hadamard gate, one can obtain a system superposition in $\{0,1 \}^n$, each state with equal probability.

I’m wondering if it’s possible to prepare the system in a state where some of the states  $|i\rangle$ have a probability of zero.

And $i$ need not be constant in some digit.

Using two qubits as an example: input $|00 \rangle$, expecting $|\psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|10\rangle +|01\rangle+|00\rangle)$. Do there exists some gate doing this?

Comment: What do you mean “has probability $0$”? You can choose to apply an arbitrary gate to any qubit that puts it into an unequal superposition. There are a number of questions on this site that address how to do that.

Comment: For example, two qubits has zero probability in 00, but then 01, 10 are allowed

Comment: you can find a unitary sending any initial state into any final state, if that's what you're asking. Or more precisely put, given any pair of states $|\psi\rangle,|\phi\rangle$, there is some unitary $U$ (actually, infinitely many such $U$) such that $U|\psi\rangle=|\phi\rangle$. See eg https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15807/55

Comment: In the general case, there is no single answer on how to create such states efficiently and it is still an ongoing field of research. A related question to your is this one: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15692/is-it-possible-to-tune-the-amplitude-of-superposition-generated-by-hadamard-gate which may provide some insight into why it is not an obvious solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/17358/10454

Comment: Do you want the states that do not have 0 amplitude to be in an equal superposition?

Answer (score 1):

you can check out qiskit textbook,

1. https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/phase-kickback.html
2. https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/density-matrix.html#5.-Mixed-States-in-the-Bloch-Sphere--

This is how you do it:

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, assemble, Aer

q = QuantumRegister(2, name = 'q')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(q)   

#Define initial state    
initial_state = [1/np.sqrt(3), 1/np.sqrt(3),1/np.sqrt(3),0]   
circuit.initialize(initial_state, [0,1])   

circuit.decompose().decompose().decompose().decompose().decompose().draw("mpl")
```

[image]